How do I eliminate Google Services files from mobile app?
For starters, I'm working with a Flutter application which is already a problem because I am not a Flutter developer (our Flutter guy is on his honeymoon so I'm not going to bother him for a while).
In any case, there are Google configuration files present in the source code, "google-services.json" in the Android source and "GoogleService-Info.plist" in iOS. My security people want me to remove them from the source code and move them to a server, and have the app download them at runtime.
I know how to move the files to a server and retrieve them, but I don't know what to do next. I can't immediately find any explicit code in the project that initializes Google or Firebase services. I do not even know whether this can be done in Flutter code for both apps or if it needs to be done in native code individually for each app.
As an aside, Google and many other services have been providing files like these for years and telling you to put them in your source code. I'm not sure I believe that they would be doing this if it was a real security risk. I'd love to go back to my security team and explain to them why this isn't a problem instead of having to fix it.
Thanks,
Frank

Have you seen: https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/learn-more#config-files-objects and specifically the last paragraphs in that section.

The values in these files are not secrets, and are in fact needed for the app to be able to find your Firebase project on the servers. Removing the files from source control is common (and OK), but downloading them at runtime adds no significant security. See my longer answer (and links) here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37482366/is-it-safe-to-expose-firebase-apikey-to-the-public
